# Phonegap: How to use sqlite in windows phone 8

Tags: windows, sqlite, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm porting over my Phonegap application I wrote for android into windows phone 8, and I'm having trouble getting sqlite to work. I know phonegap itself doesn't support sqlite yet, but there seems to be a plugin that does work:

https://github.com/marcucio/Cordova-WP-SqlitePlugin

However, I'm really struggling to get this working. I included some of the .cs files here in my Plugins folder, but to no avail. Does anyone have any ideas on how I should actually use this plugin?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_use_SQLite_in_Windows_Phone ? I am still in phase of installation and setting, but I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I got the plugin working with phonegap 2.6 and 2.7. I recently tried with 3.0 without success.

Besides the .cs files, you have to add Community.CsharpSqlite.WinPhone.dll as a Reference (it is included in the plugins package) - and of course add the plugin to your config.xml.

Remember to copy the SQLitePlugin.js to your www folder and add a referencing script tag to your index.html

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use it: https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage
it works most of the time... you can install it this way with CLI:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage
```

(last version)

or

```
 cordova plugin add https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage
```

(0.7.8)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the SQLite plugin created by Microsoft. In my experience I've found it to be very reliable and fast. https://github.com/msopentech/cordova-plugin-websql/

> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-websql

As far as I'm aware, you'll only need to make two changes to you code:

1. Wait for Cordova's **deviceready** event, as oppose to, say, **window.onload** before you attempt to do anything with the database (I guess you're probably doing that already though).
2. Make sure you're not using **readTransaction** method on the database object as it hasn't been implemented by the plugin. However, it's not a problem as you can just use **transaction** instead. The former would just be a little safer under certain circumstances as it ensures data can't be accidentally changed by the query (i.e. it would stop SQL injection attacks being able to change data).